# Notify user we would like them to clear their cookie. Provide a working button to clear cookies for user

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, cookies, woocommerce

**Explination:**

We are facing some issues with logged in users being able to checkout via wordpress's woocommerce. The fix for these few users that reached out to us was to simply clear their cookies. (Because we recently changed servers which mucked things up a bit causing this checkout issue)

So i want to provide a red bar at the top of our checkout and cart pages that recommends to our users that they update the cookies to our site. And provide a button they can click that will remove the cookie for them.

---

**Problem:**

Okay so i have this script.. Which I am told is suppose to work.

```
<a href="javascript:clearAndRedirect('start.html')">Start your bacon</a>
```

--

```
   function deleteAllCookies() {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = cookies[i];
        var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
        var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
        document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
    }
}

function clearAndRedirect(link) {
    deleteAllCookies();
```

document.location = link;
}

Start your bacon
However when i open dev tools and select the application tab. *I am able* to clear my cookie by simply right clicking and selecting clear - at which point it deletes itself and removes itself from the cookie folder.

But when I am in dev tools and use this button script to clear my cookie. The cookie remains in the file unlike if i cleared it manually by right clicking on it in dev tools. So I am unsure if its working or not. How do i properly test this?

---

Also how do i make it re-direct the user to the login page after the cookie is successfully cleared and successful? instead of just directly after the function runs.

Any help much appreciated. Not sure if its working.

Comment: whats inside deleteAllCookies()?

Comment: You can check if cookies are still in use using this Chrome extension - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg

Comment: Also, why not use JS Cookie plugin to set, remove cookies? Easier to work with - https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Comment: okay i installed the plugin and am gonna test this out. 

Do you know if my code is okay?

Also we arent using a plugin for it because all our cookies except for one age verification cookie is automatically set by wordpress/woocommerce defaults and we arent sure how to control that with a manual plugin.

Comment: Okay pretty sure my code just doesnt work then.. cuz its not clearing the cookies. it does re-direct me tho. But if i put a # in the link so it doesnt. cookies still there. and doesnt log me out when tested as a logged in customer/user

Comment: If the cookies are set as HTTP-only you can't clear them via js.

Comment: Okay but our site is set up fully with ssl right now. Or is there a problem with my code? not sure what u mean.